# Python string issue when checking the first and last character

Tags: python, string

This is the question:- Modify the first_and_last function so that it returns True if the first letter of the string is the same as the last letter of the string, False if they’re different. Remember that you can access characters using message[0] or message[-1].
Be careful how you handle the empty string, which should return True since nothing is equal to nothing.

when i write the code like this:-

```
def first_and_last(message):

    if len(message) == 0:
        return True
    elif message[0] == message[-1]:
        return True
    else:
        return False


print(first_and_last("else"))

print(first_and_last("tree"))

print(first_and_last(""))

# output:-

True

False 

True
```

But when i write the code like this:-

```
def first_and_last(message):

    if message[0] == message[-1]:
        return True
    elif len(message) == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

print(first_and_last("else"))

print(first_and_last("tree"))

print(first_and_last(""))

# output:-
True

False

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Sidje/PycharmProjects/untitled2/SId.py", line 11, in <module>
    print(first_and_last(""))
  File "C:/Users/Sidje/PycharmProjects/untitled2/SId.py", line 2, in first_and_last
    if message[0] == message[-1]:
IndexError: string index out of range
```

when i write the len fucntion with elif, the program is not working when the statement is empty but it works for the other conditions.
why is that?

Comment: that's why it says `Be careful how you handle the empty string`

Comment: ahhh, got it now :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the following case (your second code block), the "if" condition tries to access the first characters of a string that has no characters. This causes an error.

```py
if message[0] == message[-1]:  # can't access 0th element if string is empty
    return True
elif len(message) == 0:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

In the other case (your first block), this error never occurs because that  condition is never reached if the string has no characters, because the "elif" is skipped since the first condition is met.

```py
if len(message) == 0:
    return True
elif message[0] == message[-1]:  # skipped if first condition was met
    return True
else:
    return False
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response, i understood :)

Answer (score 0):

'as you are sending "(empty) value, then you are calling the function message[0], message[-1] is failing to find the values in the mentioned index:

Note The if function executes first, then remaining conidtions.'

Comment: Thanks mate, got it now :)

Answer (score 0):

```
def first_and_last(message):
    while len(message)>0:
        if  message[0]==message[-1]:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    return True

print(first_and_last("else"))
print(first_and_last("tree"))
print(first_and_last(""))
```

True
False
True

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).